# Generate labels and align in middle

Tags: swift

How can i generate a random amount of labels and align them next to each other in the middle?

I have this code to generate an label:

```
var label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(5, 196, 35,45 ))
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    label.text = "1";
    label.tag = 5;
    self.view.addSubview(label);
```

This work perfect, but how can i generate more than 1 label and set them next to each other in the middle?

like this:

[image]

The green things are my labels, and are align horizontally. How can i do this programmatically?

Comment: You want them one over each other, aligned vertically on their horizontal centers?

Comment: *"set them next to each other in the middle?"* could you clarify what this means exactly?

Comment: @DanielStorm I have eddited my post

Comment: So if there are two of them, and they are different lengths, what is the "middle"? Where should they actually do? You need to define what you want very precisely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
var lastLabel : UILabel?
var count = 1

@IBAction func addlabel(sender: AnyObject) {
    var label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    label.text = count.description;
    count++
    label.tag = 5;


    var centerX = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    centerX.priority = 999
    //This if you want to center it vertically also
    var centerY = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    var height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 35)
    var width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 45)

    label.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.view.addSubview(label);

    if let prevlabel = lastLabel {
        var align = NSLayoutConstraint(item: prevlabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.TrailingMargin, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: label, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
        //Here just add the NSLayoutConstraint you want to apply, if its only horizontal then not add  centerY

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([align, centerY, height, width, centerX])
    }else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([centerX, centerY, height, width])
    }
    lastLabel = label
}
```